# Relationship between general pictorial representations of cells and reality

Tags: cell-biology

As a novice biology student, I have seen a lot of pictorial representations of cells, from a generalised basic eukaryotic cell to specialized forms.

But is it right to visualize a cell as a 3D sphere? For instance, consider an imaginary cell where I read a cellulose cell wall surrounds a cell and a flagellum is over it. Is it right to visualize a cell as a spherical hairy ball with cross sectional cut?

A Wiki image of cell

<sup>[image: Celltypes.svg]
By Science Primer (National Center for Biotechnology Information). Vectorized by [Mortadelo2005](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Mortadelo2005). - This file has been extracted from another file, Public Domain, [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2145991)</sup>

Exceptions apart, is this 3-dimensional general representation of a cell correct? Because everywhere I see 2D images. And then comes question number 2: when Hooke and earlier workers looked at cells through the microscope, did they actually cut a cell to describe its components, assuming cells are 3 dimensional ball-like structures?

Comment: Plasmids in a prokaryote have preferred locations, like near the membrane. Not just floating everywhere.

Comment: Benefiting from millions of actual photos of cell shapes of all kinds through micrography, including annotated, colored micrographs, isn't that the best way to compare? https://www.google.com/search?q=100x+magnification+cell+annotated&tbm=isch cell shapes are so varied, from sperms to eggs to bacilla and spirals and diatoms. https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=APwXEdekgZkPlhGmqI94nl_wD5ypVBqaaw:1687346099753&q=unicellular+magnification&tbm=isch

Answer (score -1):

It is right insofar as conjuring the basic image of a cell. Cells come in all shapes and sizes, to use a cliche. Muscle cells are long, sinewy things, neurons have dendrites like a spiderweb, glial cells wrap around axons like glue. So while it may be useful in visualizing the basic concept of a cell, realistically if you were to build an organism only out of these prototypical cells, it would not be an organism but a collection of amorphous tissue, if that; and it wouldn't be alive. Organisms require specialization; cells specialize. That's why pluripotent stem cells are so highly sought after, that they're able to transform and produce any type of cell needed.